# Creating indicator across rows

Tags: sql, sas, indicator

I'm looking to create an indicator across rows to see if a company sells apples. For example, given a dataframe:

```
Company |   Product |   Salesperson    
A           Apple       John
A           Banana      John
A           Orange      Jane
B           Orange      John
B           Banana      Sam
```

I would like to create a dummyvar column to mark all of company A with a 1 because John sells apples there

```
Company |   Product |   Salesperson    |  IND  
A           Apple       John              1
A           Banana      John              1
A           Orange      Jane              1
B           Orange      John              0
```

I would like to do this in sas or SQL.

Comment: Why did you eliminate one row from the result set?

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to do in PROC SQL since SAS will automatically remerge the detail rows with the summary statistics.  Boolean expressions evaluate as 0/1 so just take the MAX() to find out if the expression is ever true.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as 
  select *,max(product='Apple') as IND
  from have
  group by company
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom ! however, i wanted to create the dummyvar as well. What I ended up doing is 
     Create table apple_table as
          select distinct company from have where product ='Apple'

Then i left joined it back in to the original data as final table left join apple_table casting IND as where product is null as 0. so all of A has a 1 and B does not. (I'm doing this over multple columns later because if John is still selling apples I want to be able to visit John across companies if he ever works for B.

Comment: @ASavage  I am not sure what you asking in this comment. The code in this answer will select all data and add one new one named IND which will either by true or false. That is either 1 or 0.  Grouping by COMPANY makes the values for the new column a constant for the same value of COMPANY.

Comment: If you also require that the apples are sold by John then add that condition to the logic expression inside the MAX() aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL Server**: a solution could be this:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    company varchar(1)
    ,product varchar(10)
    ,salesPerson varchar(10)
)

insert into @tbl values ('A', 'Apple', 'John')
insert into @tbl values ('A', 'Banana', 'John')
insert into @tbl values ('A', 'Orange', 'Jane')
insert into @tbl values ('B', 'Orange', 'John')
insert into @tbl values ('B', 'Banana', 'Sam')

SELECT
    company
    ,product
    ,salesPerson
    ,CASE WHEN 
        company IN (SELECT company FROM @tbl WHERE product = 'Apple' AND salesPerson = 'John') THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS col
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table is name is X and IND column already exist with null values.

```
update X
     SET IND = 1
     WHERE Company IN (select distinct(Company) from X where Product = 'Apple' AND Salesperson = 'John')

update X
     SET IND = 0
     WHERE Company NOT IN (select distinct(Company) from X where Product = 'Apple' AND Salesperson = 'John')
```